# What is cache size measured in?

Tags: qgis, cache

Can anyone tell me what the units are for the Cache Size setting in QGIS please? Is it bytes, KB, Mb, MB?

When I look in the directory specified by the path (/Users/.../.qgis/cache/) the cache folder is just 6KB.

Any assistance appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 4):

Byte (see [QNetworkDiskCache::setMaximumCacheSize](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkdiskcache.html)).

The cache is mainly used for WMS-C/WMTS - so you're probably not using that.